# Summing up magnetic fields

Tags: electromagnetism, superposition

In the case of a complex shape filiform distribution of current, are we allowed to determine the magnetic field created by sections of the distribution and then summing them up, like we do with a discrete distribution of charge when calculating the electric field?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, absolutely.  In other words, the magnetic field also obeys [the principle of superposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superposition_principle).  This does break down if you consider back-reaction (i.e. the currents feel [Lorentz forces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_force) from the magnetic fields); but it should always be fine for static systems.

Comment: Does the direction of the current matter? 

For example if I have a semi- circle and I calculated its magnetic field when I moves clockwise. Is the magnetic field identical if I moves counterclockwise ?

Comment: Yes, opposite current produces an opposite direction magnetic field.  Generally one uses the [right-hand rule](http://physicsed.buffalostate.edu/SeatExpts/resource/rhr/rhr.htm)

Comment: I am a little confused because I don't see how the direction of the current will involve in the Biot-Savart law..

Comment: In the Biot-Savart law, the current is a vector - so it includes direction.